# Display tags in form

Tags: odoo

Given a custom model named 'Foo', I would like to add "tags" to it.

The code I am using:

```
class FooTag(models.Model):
    _name = 'foo_tag'
    _description = 'Foo Tag'
    tag = fields.Char('Tag')

class Foo(models.Model):
    _name = 'foo'
    _description = 'Foo Model'
    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)
    content = fields.Text('Foo Content')
    tag_ids = fields.Many2many('foo_tag', string='Tags')
```

Here is the code for the view:

```
<record id="view_form_foo" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Foo Form</field>
    <field name="model">foo</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Foo">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="tag_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
                    <field name="content"/>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

So far, so good.

But in the view I get the relationship (foo_tag,1) rather than the actual Tag name given. How could I display column 'Tag' of foo_tag instead of the relationship?

I have seen this post, but shows old API, **any place where I can find an example for new API (Odoo 10)**?

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/many2many-tags-show-a-refrence-of-the-tag-not-the-name-24000

Answer (score 0):

I got in another forum that:

1. Either 'tag' field is renamed to 'name' in foo_tag model.
2. _rec_name = 'tag' is added to foo_tag model.

This solves the issue.